# How to bind the mesh elements in the OBJ model to a box in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I need to move a mesh element inside the obj model, all I want to do is bind the element in the OBJ model to Object3d, but I can't see it after it's added. I don't know what happened.

```
var box = new THREE.Object3D();
box.add(mesh);
scene.add(box);
```

Comment: there is not enough information here to help you solve your issue.

Comment: Can you show the code that generates the mesh? Even better would be a full piece of reproducible example code.

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve